# I am trying to iterate through an array of ids and insert a mongodb document if an id is not present. How can i get them to persist?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am working with Node JS and mongodb and I have a collection of documents with ids from 1-5000. However there are some ids that are missing and I want each document to have one ID.

Here is the code I'm working with:

```
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/test", function(err, db) {
    if(err) {
        console.log("Unable to connect", err);
        return;
    } 

    console.log("We are connected");

    var collection = db.collection('examples');

    collection.aggregate(
        [
            {"$sort": {"user_id": 1} },
            {"$out": "users"}
        ]
    ).toArray(function(err, docs) {
        var toSave = [];
        db.collection('users').find().toArray(function(err, docs){
            docs.forEach(function(doc){
                toSave.push(doc.user_id);
            })

            for (var i = 1; i < 5000; i++) {

                if (toSave.indexOf(i) == -1) {
                    db.collection('examples').insert({
                        user_id: i,
                        create_dt: new Date()
                    })
                }
            }

            console.log(toSave);
            db.close()
        })
    });
});
```

I was hoping this would go through my toSave array and insert documents for each of the missing user_id's but when I check my database it only ever creates one document.

How can I get all of the documents to save in the database?

Comment: Sorry but I don't get the point of this exercise. Firstly you are just getting all "user_id" values from the "example" collection, and just sorting and really not using `.aggregate()` for anything really other than just writing those into another collection. Kind of a waste, but there's more wrong. Then you are just iterating all of those results and trying to insert them back into the "same" "example" collection. So there really isn't anything to miss. Perhaps you thought your aggregate was "appending" output. It does not. It simply overwrites. Nothing is being done here.

Answer (score -1):

I agree with @Blakes. It appears to me that you really want to find documents containing a user_id field which must be updated, and then update that field with some appropriate value. For example, the user_id field might be null, or it contains a duplicate value. Suppose you have two documents that each have a user_id of 81:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56c519bac62ffdbd22b000fd"), "user_id" : 81, "stuff" : 11 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56c519cbc62ffdbd22b000fe"), "user_id" : 81, "stuff" : 12 }
```

Changing the user_id field can be done by calling the updateOne() method of the MongoDB javascript driver.

Here is example code:

```
db.collection('examples2').find(query).toArray(function(err, docs) {
        if (err) throw (err)
        docs.forEach(function (doc) {
            if (doc.user_id === 81) {
                dcnt++
                im_array.push(doc._id)
                console.dir(doc)
            }
            if (doc.user_id === "") {  //empty?
                dcnt++
                im_array.push(doc._id)
                console.dir(doc)
            }
        })
    })
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("\nPrinting list of objectids\n")
        for (var i = 0; i < im_array.length; i++) {
            console.log(im_array[i])
        }
        console.log("\nUpdating Documents...\n")
        for (var j = 0; j < im_array.length; j++) {
            idObj = new ObjectID(im_array[j])
            db.collection('examples2').updateOne( { "_id" : idObj }, { "$set" : { "user_id" : j + 27 } }, function(err2, doc2) {
                if (err2) throw err2

            })
        }
    }, 5000)

    setTimeout(function() {
        db.collection('examples2').find( { "user_id" : 10 })
        console.log('\nTotal number of documents processed ' + dcnt + '\n')
        db.close()
    }, 12000)
```

Since processing is asynchronous, I'm being a bit crude and using setTimeout() where perhaps using promises-based processing is better.

In any case, the above code will update the documents containing a user_id field equal to 81:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56c519bac62ffdbd22b000fd"), "user_id" : 27, "stuff" : 11 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56c519cbc62ffdbd22b000fe"), "user_id" : 28, "stuff" : 12 }
```

Consider creating a unique index on the user_id field as well. This way, any code that attempts to create or update a document without including a properly formatted user_id will fail.

Comment: Really not seeing the problem addressed here because the question itself is very obtuse. The code in the question is taking content from collection "examples" and ultimately trying to write that back to the same collection "examples". Therefore there would be no point. The statement *"..missing ids.."* implies that there is another source "somewhere". But until the OP says where that really is, then there is nothing to answer. You're the second person to "just" address the "flow control" issue with callbacks ( the other answer is deleted, and you have less than 10k rep required to see that ).

Comment: So the problem here is really about "reading the question" and realizing the question does not make any sense. It doesn't need answers right now, it needs the OP to clarify. And your approach to waiting for callbacks using "timeouts" is plain **horrible!**. I seriously hope you have not written any production code that actually does this.